# How to extract the video ID from a Vimeo URL in Android

Tags: android, vimeo

I have the following URL. How to extract the id '4954868' in Android?

```
"https://vimeo.com/4954868"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for an answer in Kotlin or in Java.
This is the Java version:

```
String videoUrl = "https://vimeo.com/4954868";
String id = videoUrl.substring(videoUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, videoUrl.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ways:

```
final String BASE_URL = "https://vimeo.com/";
String url = "https://vimeo.com/4954868";
String id = url.replace(BASE_URL, "")

// Kotlin version
val id = url.removePrefix(BASE_URL)
```

or

```
String url = "https://vimeo.com/4954868";
String[] parts = url.split("/")
String id = parts[parts.size - 1]
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**kotlin:**

```kotlin
val url = "https://example.com/123456"
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

result :`123456`